# Google Maps API Autocomplete doesn't return same result as a Google Maps Search

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

No result is returned when using the Google Maps API v3. Autocomplete, however when doing a Google Maps Search for the same address will return a result.

Why is this and how can this be resolved?

---

Example.

- **Works**:

  Google maps, finds the address: 
  https://www.google.co.uk/maps?q=1+Oakland+Terrace,+New+Edlington,+Doncaster+DN12+1AA
- **Fails**:

  Step 1. Use the example of the Maps API Autocomplete.  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

  Step 2. Start typing or paste in the address:

  > 1 Oakland Terrace, New Edlington, Doncaster DN12 1AA.

  No address is found.

Comment: Have you tried [biasing the autocomplete to the UK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#set_search_area)?

Comment: That doesn't seem to help.

Comment: why is this voted to close ?

Comment: I dont think it will show autocomplete address, even you start typing that address in `https://www.google.co.uk/maps`. If you try `1 Oakland Terrace, Doncaster`,  then it will show a autocomplete suggestion in both the example and `https://www.google.co.uk/maps`.

Comment: If I do the above, it is converted to `1 Oakland Avenue, Hatfield, Doncaster District, UK`

Comment: @geocodezip Yes I have tried this. No change in the accuracy.

Comment: @ztan Yes, but this is not the same address as the postcode it gives is DN7 6JL which is different from the original.
This is a correct address and should be found.

Comment: @NimChimpsky I believe because it is too broad. I am not sure how to narrow it down though...

Answer (score 0):

The Google Places API often returns results similar to maps.google.com, but they're not the exact same.  I'm unable to reproduce any suggestions for the start of this address using maps.google.com, which matches the experience you're seeing in the Autocomplete API.

That said, this specific address appears to work correctly using the [Geocoding API](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1%20Oakland%20Terrace,%20New%20Edlington,%20Doncaster%20DN12%201AA) and the [Place Text Search API](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=1%20Oakland%20Terrace,%20New%20Edlington,%20Doncaster%20DN12%201AA&key=.....).  The Places API has information for that address, it's just not autocompleting.  I would recommend designing your application so that if you have a full-looking address and an autocomplete request fails you fall back to a regular Places API text search or geocoding call.